# No row with the given identifier exists

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have 2 pojo. One pojo represents a view, V_EMPLOYEE in my Oracle database.
View V_EMPLOYEE:

```
+----------+----------+
| ID       | TEMP     |
+----------+----------+
| 1        |    0     |
| 2        |    1     |
| 3        |    0     |
| 4        |    1     |
+----------+----------+
```

TEMP is of type VARCHAR2(1)

The Employee POJO is as follows:

```
public class EmpPOJO {
private int ID;
private String Temp;

//getters and setters
}
```

My other pojo represents a table corr_comp_emp:

```
    +----------+----------+----------+
    | ID       | ID_COM   |   ID_EMP |
    +----------+----------+----------+
    | 1        |    2     |    2     | 
    | 2        |    3     |    5     | 
    | 3        |    5     |    6     | 
    | 4        |    8     |    8     | 
    +----------+----------+----------+
```

The pojo is as follows:

```
public class CorrComEmp {
private int ID;
private EmpPOJO Emp;
private ComPojo com;

//getters and setters
}
```

The query I am using to get a list of CorrComEmp is :

```
listE = session.createQuery("SELECT it FROM pojo.CorrComEmp as it, " + V_EMPLOYEE
                        + " as vue WHERE vue.Id = it.Emp").list();
```

Whenever my project hits the above code, it gets the following error:

```
No row with the given identifier exists: 5, of class: pojo.EmpPOJO
```

The employee 5 is present in the view V_EMPLOYEE.  I have noticed that I am getting this error after having added the new property to Employee, TEMP.
I have tried inserting date in the corr_comp_emp table through hibernate and it works correctly.  It is only retrieving data which gives this error.
Any idea what I am missing?  I am stuck with this prob since a week.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Your query selects an unknown entity ComEmp, but you say it's supposed to return a List<CorrComEmp>. It uses an unknown constant V_EMPLOYEE. No naming convention is respected. Please rework your question by providing all the eccessary details correctly, and choosing a better naming. What's wrong with `Employee`, `Company`, and `Contract` for your entities, for example? Also, you say that the row with ID 5 exists, but your table screenshot shows that it doesn't. Again, very confusing.

Answer (score -1):

Possible reasons are:

1. Persistence - the data for employee 5 is not persisted. The data
   might have been entered by one transaction and somehow not
   committed. But if another transaction tries retrieving the data in
   another session, you will get this error.
2. The transaction made
   through hibernate is getting rolled back

Answer (score -1):

I dont know java/hibernate, but as far as Oracle is concerned, your query has multiple obvious error.

1. While using alias for table names, you cannot use `as`. So your query should be something like
2. There is no column named `it` which you mentioned in select clause.
3. Table `pojo.ComEmp` in `from` clause doesn't exist as database will not know what `pojo.ComEmp` is .

**You should first run your query in sqlplus/Oracle SQL Developer or any other client tool, to verify if the query is correct. User hardcoded variable values to run the query wherever applicable.**

For example, the closest working version of your query will be below. Not sure if you want to join on any other column.

```
SELECT it.id FROM corr_comp_emp it 
     inner join V_EMPLOYEE vue 
on vue.Id = it.Id;
```